# What String.substr(negative number) does?

Tags: javascript, substring, substr

I found this snippet, but I am not sure if it should have `-5` or `-6`, because I do not what exactly `substr(negative)` does.

```
('00000'+(15).toString(16)).substr(-5)
```

Comment: why so many downvotes?  Better than some dumb questions being asked.

Comment: @user2310289 - Because the OP could have just as easily opened his browser console and checked this in 5 seconds.

Comment: @user2310289: "The question does not show any research effort." I mean, even w3schools documents this. And there's MDN, and the spec, and...

Comment: Fair enough, but no votes to close?  And so many votes for the @techfoobar - strange.

Comment: @user2310289 Do not try to understand SO voting mechanism.

Comment: @fiscblog - This is the best advise I have had all year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**[`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** returns the a string made up of the ***last*** `N` characters, when `-N` is passed to it.

`"Hello".substr(-2)` => `"lo"`

**From the docs:**

> If start is negative, substr uses it as a character index from the end
> of the string. If start is negative and abs(start) is larger than the
> length of the string, substr uses 0 as the start index.

Answer (score 4):

In general:

```
str.substr(-n)
```

Is the same as:

```
str.substr(str.length-n)
```

Which is the same as:

```
str.substr(str.length-n,str.length)
```

Which returns the sub-string:

```
str[str.length-n,...,str.length-1]
```